# Your app hosts extension(s) but it does not comply with the App Extension Programming Guide

Tags: iphone, ios8, custom-keyboard

Your app hosts extension(s) but it does not comply with the App Extension Programming Guide.

Specifically, your app extension must be universal and work on iPhone, iPod touch, and iPad.

Next Steps

Please use the targeted device family build setting in Xcode, specifying the “iPhone/iPad” value, to declare that your app extension is universal.

Resources

For additional instructions on configuring for the universal targeted device family, please see the section, Ensure Your iOS App Extension Works on All Devices, in the App Extension Programming Guide.

My app got rejected and I am getting this response from apple.I have already applied these changes still my app rejected.Any help would be appreciated.
             Thanks

Comment: Is there a question here?  (It reads as if you've already been given a solution.)

Comment: I have already applied these changes.But still apple rejected my app.

Comment: If you have verified that the fixed version works on "iPhone, iPod touch, and iPad", it's not really a technical problem any more.  I believe there's an appeal process.

Comment: okay...Thanks..I will try to make an appeal...